# Clean my code with reflection

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection

I want to loop through my Car class with reflection to remove all null values and replace them with better values like string = "".

```
    [Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    public string model;
    public int year;
    public List<Owner> owner;
}

[Serializable()]
public class Owner
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}
```

I have made this so far

```
   public void LoopEverythingAndFix(object type)
    {
        var prop = type.GetType().GetFields();

        foreach (var fieldInfo in prop)
        {
            if (GetType(fieldInfo))
            {
                var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(type);

                if (value == null)
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(type, GetDefaultValue(fieldInfo));
            }
            else
            {
                LoopEverythingAndFix(fieldInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    public bool GetType(System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(bool))
            return true;

        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(int))
            return true;

        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(decimal))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

The `GetType` method is to know if current field is a class like "owner" class or if its a value/reference field like int/string,and if it is a type of "owner" then i want to loop that to and fix those properties as well.

The problem is when it finds "owner" in car class, and goes to execute :

```
 LoopEverythingAndFix(fieldInfo);
```

thats where the problem is, because i send `fieldInfo` to the method `LoopEverythingAndFix` and when it goes back in the loop it gets 0 fields at `type.GetType().GetFields()`. It is a list and i want to loop the listitems and send them to the LoopEverythingAndFix method

Comment: why do you want to set to empty string instead of keeping the null ? And if you actually do need such behavior, can't you simply set the default value in the class like `[Serializable()]public class Car{   public string model = null;    public int year;    public Owner owner;}`

Comment: Why don't you just init your fields with empty strings?  This seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call `LoopEverythingAndFix` on the Reflection type `FieldInfo` rather than the actual object you want to fix.

To fix, replace this:

```
LoopEverythingAndFix(fieldInfo);
```

With this:

```
LoopEverythingAndFix(fieldInfo.GetValue(type));
```

Comment: hope u reading this, i changed the code a bit :/ hope u can help me again

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that instead of passing in an Owner object, you are passing in a reference to the static class Owner.  So you already have the Type of the owner.

Answer (score 0):

**There are a few issues with your code that need to be addressed:**

1. You are performing a null check on known value types.  A ValueType instance other than a `Nullable<T>` will never be null.  This action is unnecessary and hurts performance.  I have fixed this below.
2. You are not accounting for the circumstance of a null reference type field other than `string`.  For example, what should happen if there is a null `Owner` or a null `List<Owner>`?
3. Since you did not post the `GetDefaultValue()` function, it's signature is a bit unclear.  My guess is that it accepts a `FieldInfo` and resolves the default non-null value based on the field type. Since, this in actuality is only applicable to a `string` argument, it would be better to replace the call with `string.Empty`.  I have pointed this out in a comment below.

Below, I have consolidated, optimized and rewritten your function below, with comments to indicate where different behaviors must be changed or inserted.

```
public void LoopEverythingAndFix(object instance)
{
    var fields = instance.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
    foreach(var fieldInfo in fields){
       var fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
       if(!fieldType.IsValueType){
          bool isString = fieldType == typeof(string);
          var fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
          if(fieldValue != null){
                if(!isString){
                    // This should recursion be called when the type is a 
                    // complex (non-string) reference type that is not null
                    LoopEverythingAndFix(fieldValue);
                }
                // You don't need to fix a non-null string value
          }
          else{
              if(isString){
                  // since you didn't post the code for this, I am assuming 
                  // it works correctly, but it may be that you can just replace
                  // GetDefaultValue(fieldInfo) with string.Empty 
                  fieldInfo.SetValue(instance, GetDefaultValue(fieldInfo));
              }
              else{
                  // It is unclear how you want to handle a complex reference type 
                  // field with a null value.  That code should go here.
              }
          }
       } 
    }
}
```